# Using Scispark can we know all the variables included in a netcdf file ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

val data = sc.NetcdfDFSFile("/home/akhilav/Downloads/120mb.nc",variable,3)
here i give variable  as latitude. beacause I know the variables.If we r not familiar with variables how can we extract from netcdf file through code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import org.dia.loaders.NetCDFReader
...
netcdfPath = "--**PATH TO A NETCDF FILE**--"
varNames = NetCDFReader.loadNetCDFVar(netcdfPath)
```

The only caveat here is that the netcdfPath string needs to be a local path not an HDFS path. loadNetCDFVar() opens a netcdffile, extracts all its variables, and returns it as a list of strings. You can then pass that list when calling the NetcdfDFSFile() function.

Comment: if i want only the variables included in data part .then how its work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193802/read-netcdf-file-above-1gb-using-scispark